# Multi-page SVG in the browser

Tags: web, svg

Is there any support for working with multipage SVGs in a modern web browser for displaying and printing purposes?

I've been trying to find the answers in google. But no mention anywhere of multipage SVGs in the browser.

Comment: What is a multi-page svg?

Comment: An svg with a pageset node containing page nodes contains what to display on each page. Version 1.2 onwards supports it in the file format. Was hoping to have an textbased alternative to a pdf as a doc format.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/WD-SVG12-20041027/multipage.html actually just a part of a working draft. Maybe multipage isn't supported.

Comment: That's a cool concept, thanks for explaining it!

Answer (score 3):

Shot myself  in the foot. Multipage svg was just a part of v1.2 working draft and was dropped in v2.0.

Comment: Thx for the Update. Its a pitty. Besides the old TIFFs, this would have been a great way to store images/icons as sets in just one file.